# Spring Webflux WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I don't really know how to translate the following call to the spring webflux webclient correctly.

userIds is the List and I was able to call the service using the following syntax but I could not get that working with the Spring WebFlux WebClient.  Please help me if there is any of you know how to do it.

```
String url = "http://profile.service.com/v1/profiles/bulk";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

ResponseEntity<List<MiniProfile>> responseEntity;
try {
    responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new 
    HttpEntity(userIds, headers), new 
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MiniProfile>>() {});
} catch (RestClientException e) {
    responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<MiniProfile>>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

return responseEntity.getBody();
```

This is the way I got it translate to the Webflux WebClient:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.fromIterable(userIds);
return readWebClient.post().uri("/v1/profiles/bulk")
      .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(flux, String.class))
      .retrieve().bodyToFlux(MiniProfile.class);
```

Comment: what's not working with your current solution? What result are you getting? What were you expecting instead?

Comment: I got an 500 error code which I could not know where it came from and here is the stack trace.   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: ClientResponse has erroneous status code: 500 Internal Server Error.  And I expect our service returns a list of profiles.  Note the old code with RestTemplate worked fine for me.

Comment: that's an important piece of information that belongs in your question, really. This says that the server responds with HTTP 500. So the requests must be different between RestTemplate and WebClient.

Comment: I agree that the requests must be different between the RestTemplate and WebClient.  I've been trying to see if the requests were different between them but I could only see the request body of the RestTemplate got translated as the array of string like this ["0449b652-0006-0000-0000-000000000000", "0333b652-0006-0000-0000-000000000000"] which worked fine with our dependency service but I could not see the request in Netty WebClient as a json like the RestTemplate so I could not tell what the differences were.  Do you have any idea how I can see the serialized request body in Netty WebClient?

Comment: You can set the logging level like this: `logging.level.reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ContextHandler=debug` `logging.level.reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient=debug` in your `application.properties` file

Comment: @BrianClozel After adding debug levels, a large sections of log looks like tcp dump. Is there a way to view the body as text in the log file?

Answer (score 1):

You should not change your list to flux, you should send it as list like this

```
return readWebClient.post()
  .uri("/v1/profiles/bulk")
  .syncBody(userIds)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MiniProfile>>() {})
  .flatMapIterable(Function.identity());
```

this code is not tested but the principe is the same

Comment: thanks for your time to answer my question but there was nothing wrong with your code or my code but the real issue was on our .NET stack when we use Webflux Webclient to put or post on .NET stack we need to handle the raw request in .NET stack.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to use WebClient for reactive call such this.

```java
@Autowired
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

```java
webClientBuilder.build().post()
                .uri("http://profile.service.com/v1/profiles/bulk")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(new YourBodyClass()),YourBodyClass.class))
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                })
                .retrieve().bodyToFlux(MiniProfile.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.bodyValue(userIds)` or `.syncBody(userIds)` (Deprecated) instead of body with Body inserter

Answer (score 0):

**you can refer below mentioned code snippets **

```
WebClient.post().uri(endPointUrl)
           .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
          .body(Mono.just(xmlEntity), String.class)
          .retrieve()
```